# Docker container running in multiple ports instead of specified port

Tags: docker, deployment, jboss, ansible

I am trying to run docker image using ansible using following module

```
 - name: run the image in a docker container                                        
    docker_container:                                                                     
      name: deploy1                                                                    
      image: redhat-jboss                                                                                                                               
      state: started                                                                
      exposed_ports:                                                                  
        - 8089/tcp"
```

but the container is exposed in multiple ports.

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID- 18f8hddd237                                                         IMAGE    18f8hddd237                
COMMAND  "/docker-entrypoint.…"               
CREATED     11 seconds ago                                                      
STATUS      Up 10 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                        NAMES      redhat-jboss                                                             
PORTS        22/tcp, 3528-3529/tcp, 4447/tcp, 4712-4713/tcp, 5432/tcp, 5445/tcp, 5455/tcp, 7500/tcp, 7600/tcp, 8009/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8089-8090/tcp, 8443/tcp, 8787/tcp, 9990/tcp, 9999/tcp, 23364/tcp, 45700/tcp, 57600/tcp   deploy1
```

Let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm not able to find or view that repository but could it be that the tag is incorrect, possibly try a different tag version?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ports` instead of `exposed_ports`.
In your case it should be something like:

```
name: run the image in a docker container
docker_container:
  name: deploy1
  image: redhat-jboss
  state: started
  ports: 
    - '0.0.0.0:8089:8089'
```

Explanation. There are two different parameters in ansible [docker_container](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/docker_container_module.html) module:

- `exposed_ports` is "List of additional container ports which informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime. If the port is already exposed using EXPOSE in a Dockerfile, it does not need to be exposed again.". So this just extends Dockerfile's EXPOSE ports with what you added.
- `published_ports` (aliased `ports`): "List of ports to publish from the container to the host." These are ports that really will be connected to host's ports.

For more information on how to open ports you may read in the [official documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/docker_container_module.html) to the module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried above mentioned one but still no change. 
Now the output is 
22/tcp, 3528-3529/tcp, 4447/tcp, 4712-4713/tcp, 5432/tcp, 5445/tcp, 5455/tcp, 7500/tcp, 7600/tcp, 8009/tcp, 8080/tcp, 8090/tcp, 8443/tcp, 8787/tcp, 9990/tcp, 9999/tcp, 23364/tcp, 45700/tcp, 57600/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8089->8089/tcp

Comment: Actually, only 8089 is opened to the external connections (is published to the host machine).
[EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) instruction in the Dockerfile is used to document which ports container listens internally.
In docker ps -a response if there is no "some_port->" part of the notation, then port is not published yet, but can be. Your host's ports like 3528-3529, 4447 and others should not be used now. (Moreover 22 is sshd port and if you are running on the host with sshd on it, you won't be able to bind to that port for your container).

Answer (score 0):

Are exposed ports accessible to the host system by default? **No.**
Are exposed ports accessible to linked containers? **Yes.**
Are exposed ports accessible to other containers? **No.**

**What is an exposed port?**
An exposed port is basically your docker image saying: "These ports are available for *outside* communication. But you have to publish them first."

Note: *outside* means outside its own network. If you link containers together, they can communicate through the exposed ports.

**Where are exposed ports defined?**
The exposed ports you are seeing are defined in the `Dockerfile` of the image you are running ( or in one of the parents ). These are defined with the [`EXPOSE <portnumber>`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) syntax.

You can also define additional exposed ports when you start a container, which you're doing in the `expose_ports` section of your `docker-compose.yml` file.

**How do you make exposed ports accessible**
To access an exposed port, you have to **publish** it, then it will be available on the host. To publish an exposed port, you specify these ports in the `ports` part of your `docker-compose.yml` file, or with the `-p` argument when starting the container ( e.g. `-p 22` to expose it to a random port, `-p 22:2222` to expose it to port `2222` on the host, etc ).

Further reading on [EXPOSE vs publish](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/expose-vs-publish-docker-port-commands-explained-simply-434593dbc9a3).